# Loading a sdf file in gazebo

Tags: gazebo-model, sdformat, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am loading a sdf file. But when loading it gives a following error

```
[Wrn] [ModelDatabase.cc:340] Getting models from[http://gazebosim.org/models/]. This may take a few seconds
```

what I know is this problem is occuring may be due to meshes I'm adding.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24695/loading-a-sdf-file-in-gazebo/) by [me_saw](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25048/me_saw/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the uri i was using model://[path of the mesh] so it was searching in ~/.gazebo/models in which i don't have these meshes is it was prompting thus error. I changed the uri to path of the mesh and it worked perfectly

---

Originally posted by [me_saw](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25048/me_saw/) with karma: 1 on 2020-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0